# React jwt authentication always redirects to login page

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm trying to make a `jsonwebtoken` based authentication.
Instead of redirecting to the `/select` route after clicking on login the page just refreshes and prompts me to log in again, but token is fetched from my REST API and saved to `localStorage`. How can I fix the issue?

I'm using `react-redux` and `redux-thunk` for dispatch.

App.js

```
class App extends React.Component {
componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchUser();
}

render() {
    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Switch>
                <Route exact={true} path="/login" component={Login}/>
                <PrivateRoute exact={true} path="/select" component={ChooseVA}/>
                <PrivateRoute exact={true} path="/" component={HomePage}/>
            </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}

//Assing actions to App as props
export default connect(null, actions)(App);
```

PrivateRoute.js

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ isLoggedIn, ...props }) => {

switch (isLoggedIn) {
    case null:
        return <div></div>;
    case false:
        return <Redirect to="/login" />;
    default:
        return <Route {...props} />;
   }
};

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
       isLoggedIn: state.authenticationProperty
    };
}

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps)(PrivateRoute));
```

Login.js (only handleSubmit)

```
  handleSubmit = (event) => {
   event.preventDefault();
    //Send data to server

   axios.post('/auth/login/web', {
      email: this.state.email,
      key: this.state.password
    }).then((res) => {
      if ('localStorage' in window && window.localStorage !== null) {
        localStorage.setItem('tkn', res.data.t);
        this.setState({toDashBoard: true});
       } else {
        window.alert('This Browser is not Supported! Please update!');
      }

   });
}
```

Auth Reducer:

```
export default function (state = null, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case FETCH_USER:
            return action.payload;
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

`fetchUser()` action:

```
export const fetchUser = () => {
return function(dispatch) {
    if (!getJwt()) {
        dispatch({
            type: FETCH_USER,
            payload: false
        });
    } else {
        let axiosConfig = {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
                'access-key': '1',
                'x-auth': getJwt()
            }
        };

        axios
            .get('/auth/me', axiosConfig)
            .then((user) => {
                dispatch({
                    type: FETCH_USER,
                    payload: user.data
                });
            }).catch(res => {
            localStorage.removeItem('tkn');
            dispatch({
                type: FETCH_USER,
                payload: false
            });
        });
     }
  };
};
```

Comment: Hard to tell exactly from the code you provided, but the thing I see may be a problem here is that in handle submit function in login.js you only set your token to local storage and update your login component state: localStorage.setItem('tkn', res.data.t);
this.setState({toDashBoard: true}); Maybe you should dispatch FETCH_USER here as well, so your private route could recognize that user's been logged in? I assume you set "toDashBoard" to true in login component state for further redirect?

Comment: Why not using history.push(url) in handleSubmit for redirect?

Comment: @DmitriUsanov your method gave me some good results but, it works 50/50, sometimes i need to click the login button twice for it to redirect

Comment: Can't see what you did exactly, but maybe your authenticationProperty in not yet set to true when it hits PrivateRoute check after redirect. Check your your code to ensure that reducer changes state before redirect. Maybe you should map authenticationProperty to your login component, check its value in componentWillReceiveProps and redirect if it's true. In this case you'll also redirect authed user if he somehow gets to login (or register) page after being already authorized

Comment: So yes, I think my advice "Why not using history.push(url) in handleSubmit for redirect?" is not correct about using push in handleSubmit